# How can I sort a list of words by frequency or by hsk level?

Tags: vocabulary

I have a list of Chinese words. Is there a tool that will allow me to sort them in order of frequency or by hsk level?

Answer (score 3):

I found a tool here: https://hskhsk.pythonanywhere.com/hanzi

**Sample input:**

> [image]

**Sample output:**

> [image]